# Access to Windows 8 live id

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

I want to create an app, where users can rate stuff, but I don't want that they can rate one place multiple times. So I tought I could use the live ID of the user, that Windows 8 uses by default. Is there a way for that? If not, is there another built in way to "recognize" the user, or I have to use the Live SDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way, but the Live SDK is pretty good too.